# Python file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format Error

Tags: python, bots, whatsapp

I am using this piece of code and getting the above error.

```py
def nav_green_dot(self):
    try:
        position = pt.locateOnScreen('green_dot.png', confidence=.7)
        pt.moveTo(position[0:2], duration=self.speed)
        pt.moveRel(-100, 0, duration=self.speed)
        pt.doubleClick(interval=self.click_speed)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Exception (nav_green_dot): ', e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this Problem using

```
position = pt.locateOnScreen('File Location(copy the location/path of image from image in directory) ', confidence=.7)
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, you can't access "green_dot.png". Do you have such a file saved in the same directory as the python code?

Comment: Yes, I have saved that file in the same directory.

Comment: A google search suggests that you problem may be solved by using `img = cv2.imread(r"path") `

`y = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(img)`